# Formation of optical solitons in microresonators

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics, photonics, solitons

Optical soliton formation in laser systems with devices that facilitate mode-locking such as a saturable absorber help me understand why solitons form in the first place.

However, when one considers a device like a ring microresonator which is simply a dielectric ring, why do solitons form? It has been proven that other optical structures such as continuous-waves or even chaos CAN form. However, often, solitons form.

Extensive online searching yielded no results. Some commons answers I receive are: solitons solutions are attractors (in the nonlinear dynamics sense), or simply that nature just prefers them. But these are not very convincing.

Reference:

- [Temporal solitons in optical microresonators](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphoton.2013.343), Nature Photonics, 2014.

Comment: Could you provide references about soliton formation in dielectric rings? It is not clear what you are talking about: solitons indeed usually have to do with non-linearity (which is possible dielectrics), but it could be that this word was used to refer to something else.

Comment: Solitons will probably only form under suitable conditions. Intuitively the geometric shape of the structure is probably of fairly little concern as long as its feature sizer are larger than the soliton. Since a soliton solution is (usually considered) stable, it has to be an attractor, but that sounds like a fairly cheap exchange of one term for another somewhat similar term. The hard part of the theoretical calculation would be to estimate the parameter range in which solitons are the only (stable) solution.

Comment: The linked article clearly states that the resonator is non-linear - that is the field in this resonator is described by a non-linear equation, which likely has soliton solutions in the nonlinear dynamics sense. I suggest adding to the question the key equation from the linked paper and discussing it more specifically (in terms of non-linear dynamics and the physical interpretation for resonators)